# Cant open WindowsForm in Designer

Tags: c#, .net-5, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8

After migration from NetFramework 4.5 to .Net 5.0 My WindowsForm doesnt open in Designer.

heres the output :

```
Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__30.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__25.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<-ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext()
    
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    
    Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__26.MoveNext()
```

I also looked in Microsoft app event manager and  found that :

```
 Application: DesignToolsServer.exe
    CoreCLR Version: 5.0.1522.11506
    .NET Version: 5.0.15
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
    File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
       at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.Program.<>c.<Main>b__2_0(ILoggingBuilder configure)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.Create(Action`1 configure)
       at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Server.Program.Main(String[] args, IEnumerable`1 designTimeAssemblies)
       at DesignToolsServerX64.Program.Main(String[] args)
    
And this error  too :

 DesignToolsServer.exe 
   1.100.22.12406 
   60ef187c 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   10.0.14393.2189 
   5abdad60 
   e0434352 
   0000000000033c58 
   2804 
   01d84a6e072639cd 
   \\?\C:\Users\RUKZND062\AppData\Local\Temp\WinFormsCache\ljujc3vj.lbr\DesignToolsServer.exe 
   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   39eed713-9956-4306-a2a0-7c2412a9dec7
```

What i should doing to migrate my WindowsForm from .NetFramework 4.5 and 32bit Designer to .Net5.0 and 64bit Designer? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can you view the code of the form?  I would think there'd be a red squiggly where the problem lies.

Comment: Forms Code have not any red squigglies, it compiles in debug and in release  to

Comment: simply closing VS and reopening sln worked for me